# Can I hide Console Lines with Jenkins Log Parser

Tags: logging, jenkins, output, hide, logparser

I just found the Jenkins Log Parser Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin and was wondering if it might help me with my problem, but there is close to no description about the Parse Files that you can write urself.

Down is an example of my Console Output the Build makes and there are many many lines with DEBUG - what I want now is to somehow hide them from the Console Output. Is this possible with this plugin? Or by any other way directly in jenkins.

```
    1455617636458    addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
    1455617636466   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
    1455617636467   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
    1455617636468   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
    1455617636469   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
    1455617636469   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
    1455617636470   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
    1455617636470   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\anonymous.cc070da49079449ea1508d9addffb57a.webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1455617636470   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
    1455617636471   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1455617636471   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
    1455617636471   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
    1455617636471   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
    1455617636472   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {}
    1455617636472   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
    1455617636472   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1455617636475   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
    1455617636475   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1455617636475   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: true, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\anonymous.cc070da49079449ea1508d9addffb57a.webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","st":1455617636309,"mt":1454669720000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","st":1455030447240,"mt":1454721165000}}}
    1455617636480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\anonymous.cc070da49079449ea1508d9addffb57a.webdriver-profile\extensions.json
    1455617636480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1455617636498   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636499   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
    1455617636501   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1455617636501   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636501   addons.xpi-utils    INFO    Hiding the updated system add-ons.
    1455617636502   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1455617636502   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
    1455617636502   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636502   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
    1455617636502   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636502   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"5eJxViaIyNe8","location":"app-profile","version":"2.51.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\anonymous.cc070da49079449ea1508d9addffb57a.webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1455617636309,"updateDate":1455617636309,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":3235385,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"47.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
    1455617636502   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1455617636504   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"hPG5NuzgvTEp","location":"app-global","version":"44.0.1","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1455030447240,"updateDate":1455030447240,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":24172,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"44.0.1","maxVersion":"44.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
    1455617636504   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1455617636505   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636505   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1455617636505   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1455617636505   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1455617636515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1455617636515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1455617636515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1455617636515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1455617636515   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1455617636516   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1455617636519   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1455617636717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: 
    1455617636717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for 
    1455617636717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: 
    1455617636777   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022[GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022
    1455617636884   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1455617636885   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1455617636886   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1455617636893   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1455617636894   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1455617636894   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1455617636899   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1455617636899   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1455617636941   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1455617636964   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[1][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022[GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022
    Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[1][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022|[2][GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022[GFX1-]: [D3D11] create swap chain failed: 0x887a0022
    Powerlimit: 817
    1455617653872   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
    1455617653872   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1455617653873   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
    1455617653873   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
    1455617653873   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1455617653873   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1455617653874   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1455617653874   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for 
    1455617653875   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1455617653877   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
    1455617653879   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a plugin to do this. If you don't want the output to be logged, then that should be done in the tool that's causing the output.

Comment: Well that i actually dont know, which tool it is ... because when i run the same test in visual studio or on my own in the console, there is no such output. It only appears when running it in jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old, but if someone's still looking for an answer to this..

Add a grep in your test execution command that will filter those out. E.g. 
call runMyTests.cmd|grep -v -e '^[0-9]{13,}.*'

That'll exclude all those lines from the output that start with 13 or more digits. You'll get rid of MOST of that junk.

Another option would be to pipe it into a file, type and grep that, and still archive that file just in case you might need it for some debugging later on:
call runMyTests.cmd >runmytests.log 2>&1
type runmytests.log|grep -v -e '^[0-9]{13,}.*'

Grep (and sed, awk, curl + other super useful linux tools) comes e.g. with git extensions, when you add your \bin folder into path. Or, install these tools separately from e.g. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: Thanks, was kind of still looking for an answer / gave up on getting one :)

Answer (score 0):

The marked version works for linux - but as i am working on windows i had to find a similiar version to this without installing anything.

i made it with `FINDSTR` function now - its a little bit more complicated because it only supports base functions from regex and {13} count multiplier are not supported ...

```
| findstr /v /r ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

This is the same function like the above, just in windows ... You can just install grep on windows if it is possible - in my case not - which makes it a lot easier